# Simple Layout Issue

Tags: android

I'm facing one issue with rendering a TextView and Seekbar inside a dialog.

I was practicing this tutorial from [android site](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/AudioFxDemo.html)

The issue is inside for loop the TextView & SeekBar are supposed to be added 5 times and should be displayed in the Dialog. But only a single TextView is displayed.

Here is the code:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rgroup, int rbutton) {
    String eqSettingName = ((RadioButton) findViewById(rbutton)).getText()
            .toString();
    if (eqSettingName.equals("Custom")) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Custom Equalizer");
        LinearLayout LL = new LinearLayout(this);

        short noOfBands = mEqualizer.getNumberOfBands();
        final short minEQLevel = mEqualizer.getBandLevelRange()[0]; 
        final short maxEQLevel = mEqualizer.getBandLevelRange()[1]; 

        for (short i = 0; i < noOfBands; i++) {
            short band = i;

            TextView freqTV = new TextView(this);
            freqTV.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            freqTV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            freqTV.setText((mEqualizer.getCenterFreq(band)) / 1000 + " Hz");
            LL.addView(freqTV);

            SeekBar bar = new SeekBar(this);
            bar.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            bar.setMax(maxEQLevel - minEQLevel);
            bar.setProgress(mEqualizer.getBandLevel(band));
            LL.addView(bar);


        }

        /*
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customseekbar,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.rlCustomEqualizerSeekBar));
        */
        dialog.addContentView(LL, layoutParams);
        dialog.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why is the LayoutInflater commented out?  That's probably where your error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `LinearLayout` defaults to `orientation="horizontal"`. Change it's orientation to vertical and you will see what you want.

```
LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Comment: Thanks man...but I'm new to layouts. Can you explain how it worked

Comment: @rahul s: Your layout orientation was horizontal, which means that each of your 10 widgets were displayed one to the right of the other (and hence not visible). By setting the orientation to vertical, each widgets is displayed below the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Is your LinearLayout oriented correctly?

```
LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Comment: It may not be the answer, but I've hit this problem before and that was the answer. I hate to sound facetious so I won't, but policing answers you don't see fit isn't contributing to the topic.